# How to calculate number of parameter any probability distribution takes?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Following are number of values taken by random variables

X1 = 3, X2 = 2, X3 = 2

Want to calculate number of parameter for P(X3|X2, X1). Now from last table I can have 12 values. Is that correct?
For calculating the number of the parameter can I use this formula? |val(X1)| * |val(X2)| * |val(X3)| = 3 * 2 * 2 = 12

If yes then what is the difference in joint probability and factorization. Because if I need to calculate the number of the parameter for joint distribution that will be X3 * X2 * X1 = 12.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$P(X_3=1|X_1, X_2)= 1-P(X_3=1|X_1, X_2),$$ hence you do not need really need $12$ parameters, $6$ parameters suffice to fully specify the model.

However, to fully specicy the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2, X_3$, $11$ parameters is needed, the remaining one can be recovered by using the property that probabilities sum to $1$.

Comment: In table can you specify which parameter I can exclude?

Comment: You can for example, choose the second column to exclude. Specifying the first column sufficies.

Comment: So you mean to say bottom right I can exclude? Sorry to drag this question,  but this 12 - 1 thing I have seen at many places but not able to fully grasp it, or know how to do it.

Comment: I mean you can fully specify a column explicitly and ther other one would be automatically determined. The whole idea is.... if you know the probability of getting a head from a coin toss, you should know the probability of gettign a tail isn't it? they should sum to $1$.